# Guitar distortion pedal gain

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, gain, waveform, guitar-pedal

I am working on a custom distortion pedal. Here is the circuit:

[image]

As we can see, we have the following flow:

Input buffer -> gain stage with hard clipping -> buffer -> tone control using blending between high pass and low pass filter -> another gain stage with very small gain to boost the signal back up a bit.

Everything seems to be working great up to the buffer output -> tone control input stage. When I probe this location:

[image]

I get the following waveform (note that I am varying the gain in the "hard clipping gain" stage by varying R12 from 0 to 470 kΩ, that is why we get multiple waveforms overlayed):

[image]

This is great! We see the signal oscillating about around 4.4 V, and we get good amplification (aprox. a volt amplitude) and the squaring of the waves looks excellent as the R12 resistor gets bigger.

Now, for the problem and my question:

When I probe here:

[image]

I get the following:

[image]

Bit more fancy signal shaping, some amplitude drop, and the DC bias of the signal is gone (no longer oscillating about 4.4 V). This is why I have included one more small gain stage using a BJT.

The intention was to give it a small gain, say around 1.2X to 1.5X the input signal, and to restore the DC bias to around 4.4 V to 4.5 V

However, when I probe here:

[image]

I get this weird output:

[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get my intended result from this gain stage? If you have any other general comments about my circuit please feel free to share them as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You should always stagger crossing connections so they immediately become obvious. There may be other problems but this one stuck out as quite significant.

I'll also add that the input impedance is quite unsuitable for a geetar output; geetar amps usually have an input impedance of at least 1 MΩ, whereas yours might be less than 10 kΩ. This front-end stage would be more suitable: -

[image]

Image from [here](http://beavisaudio.com/techpages/buffers/). And note the much bigger emitter resistor than your 22 Ω!! I think you may have copied the ["tube screamer"](https://www.electrosmash.com/tube-screamer-analysis) design <-- it has a 10 kΩ emitter resistor for a reason also.

Answer (score 0):

> The intention was to give it a small gain, say around 1.2X to 1.5X the input signal, and to restore the DC bias to around 4.4V to 4.5V.

Replace the last stage (Q2) with an op-amp. Something like below. Choose the R1 and R2 for the desired gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkkWGd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>